# Why is L(z)=Az+B a linear transformation in Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

Recently, I am learning complex analysis using **" Complex Analysis for mathematics and engineering"** by John H. Mathews and Russell W. Howell. In Chapter 2, it says that "...because a linear transformation can be considered to be a composition of a rotation, a magnification, and a translation", where in the text a linear transformation is defined as w=L(z)=Az+B. This is really confusing, because in linear algebra, this doesn't make sense. So, is the definition of linear transformation in complex number different from that of linear  algebra?
Thank you!

Comment: This comes from the definition of a linear function. $+b$ is the translation. $a$ is a complex number and every complex number can be written in polar form which can be realized as a rescaling and rotation.

Comment: Well, I think that I didn't express my question nicely! The question is edited. I am confused why the way of defining linear transformation in complex number can be so explicitly written in L(z)=Az+B, where A and B are complex numbers.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I understood! Is it because it is a one-dimensional linear transformation over the field C? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by linear transformations not having such an explicit definitions: Linear maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself are given by $f(x)=ax$ for $a$ a real number. As mentioned, colloquially we say a funciton is linear if it is really any affine function, i.e. we allow for translations (basically we just want the graph to be a line, $f(x)=ax+b$)

Comment: @qbert Are linear maps from R to itself defined to be f(x)=ax? I think it is the result of the definition for linear function: T(ax+y)=aT(x)+T(y). In the textbook, the linear transformation is "defined" to be L(z)=Az+B, which is an affine map that do not satisfy the definition given in Linear Algebra. So, I wonder whether this is  the universal definition of linear transformation in complex number or it is simply the author's convenient definition.

Comment: Affine is a fine word.

Comment: I really wish elementary education would switch nomenclature, but I also wish for millions of dollars, so..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very sad confusion that arises naturally as a result of poor choice of terminology in English mathematics,  which is calling functions of the form $ f (x)=ax+b $ linear functions - $ x $ be a real or complex number, it doesn't matter.

The reason for this is that those are functions whose graph is a line (be it a real or complex line).

The reason it is unfortunate is that these functions are not necessarily linear transformations, since $ f (0)=b $ is not necessarily $0 $.

But note that they are however *affine transformations*, which means that if they don't necessarily respect linear combinations, they do respect affine combinations. Other languages would more appropriately call such functions *affine functions*.

Comment: Now that I see why I am confused! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ivy You're welcome!